# Problems with building neo4j GetAll Server-Plugin

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to build the neo4j GetAll plugin. Project contains only one example class from [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2.0-RC01/community/server-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/server/plugins/GetAll.java).

When I try to run  curl `http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GetAll/graphdb/get_all_nodes`, I get the error message:

> No such ServerPlugin exception

I'm using neo4j-community-2.2.1 (on Windows) and jdk1.7.0_79.

My project consists of :

- `GetAll.java` in `org.neo4j.examples.server.plugins` package
- `META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin` file with this content: `org.neo4j.examples.server.plugins.GetAll`
- in buildpath are all jars from `%NEO4J_HOME%\lib` included.

The jar-file is built using `jar -cvf myext.jar *` and than that jar placed in %`NEO4J_HOME%\plugins`.

I have no idea, why I cannot make it work properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: run a `curl -v http://localhost:7474/db/data/` to check what extensions are registered. Provide output of `jar -tf myext.jar` as well.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. if I run http://localhost:7474/db/data/, my plugin is not shown up in extensions.

Comment: ok, I've uploaded the screenshot of the content of myjar  [here](http://s28.postimg.org/cg318pm71/jar_inhalt.png)

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot clearly shows that `GetAll.class` is located in directory `bin/org/neo4j/examples/server/plugins` instead of `org/neo4j/examples/server/plugins` (get rid of the `bin`).

Comment: I have excluded bin folder, but it still isn't shown up in extensions. Now myjar looks like [here](http://s2.postimg.org/55d4o34yx/jar.png)

Comment: exclude the nested jars in the lib folder as well - but I'm not sure if that really helps. You can write a unit test for your GetAll call by using JVM's serviceloader. The same mechanism is used internally inside Neo4j.

Comment: thank you! i've got it. the problem was at .classpath. I guess, that eclipse build it wrong . It started to work, when I'd created complete project manually with cmd